# C++: how do I remove bad input from cin?

Tags: c++, iostream

I have done some `cin` operation and before I use `cin` I want to clear its state and 
flush it. How do I do it? I know `cin.clear()` clears the error state but to flush the `cin`
buffer how do I check if it's empty and if not which of the below statements shall I use to empty it so that I can safely use `cin` later?

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
```

or

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: please see https://www.gidforums.com/t-15686.html for a general overview (first reply to OP)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems, you detected a problem and you want to get rid of erronous input, e.g., the entered line. You *could* try to get rid what `std::cin` has in its buffer but generally, this doesn't work too well as there is no guarantee that the stream has read, e.g., a complete line. Also, to make it potentially useful you'll need to make sure that `stdin` and `std::cin` are not synchronized as otherwise `std::cin` will never buffer any characters anyway:

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
// read data using std::cin

if (!std::cin) {
    // clean-up
    std::cin.clear();
    if (std::cin) {
        std::cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()); // ignore what is buffered
    }
}
```

Whether `in_avail()` will return a non-zero value depends entirely on the used stream buffer and it may ignore more than you actually want to ignore anyway. For example, if `std::cin`'s stream buffer is replaced to use the stream buffer of an `std::istringstream` it will probably consume all the character from this source.

Probably the most sensible clean-up is to `ignore()` the next character or the characters on the current line, using either

```
std::cin.ignore();
```

or

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

The `max()` of `std::streamsize` is used as a magical number to indicate that the count should not be considered a termination criteria. If you don't pass a termination character the stream will ignore characters until the end of the stream which is probably not what you want.

Comment: if I don't pass a termination character then after clearing the buffer it doesn't go to the next statement, instead it prompts for input till I enter `EOF` by `ctrl+d`

Comment: @ajay: of course: the termination conditions for `ignore()` are: 1. it has read as many characters as specified by the first argument (by default 1); 2. the termination character was conumed (by default `std::char_traits<char>::eof()` which indicates that no character should be matched); 3. the end of the stream is reached. Specifying `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` makes the count infinite and not specifying a termination characters causes the stream to never stop due to a character, i.e., it will only stop once the entire stream is consumed.

Comment: sorry but just to clear my doubt, end of the stream is reached when EOF is encountered?

Comment: @ajay: EOF == End Of File which is conventional term for reaching the input. Note, however, that streams don't necessarily encounter C‘s `EOF` but rather `std::char_traits<cT>::eof()`: this value is used as an error indicator by functions returning a `cT` (which is just `char` for the narrow streams) when there is no character to return.

Answer (score 1):

Stream buffers have the `in_avail` method. But try to simply remove the content regardless.:

```
template <class charT, class traits>
std::basic_istream<charT, traits>&
empty_buffer(std::basic_istream<charT, traits>& is)
{
    std::basic_streambuf<charT, traits>* p = is.rdbuf();
    p->pubseekpos(0, std::ios_base::in);

    return is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, this can be done with the method is_avail().
Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

int empty_stream(std::istream & is) {

    std::streambuf * pbuf = std::cin.rdbuf();
    std::streamsize size = pbuf->in_avail();

    if(size)
    {
        if(!is.good())
            return 0;
        is.sync();
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}

int main() {

    char str[50];

    std::cin >> str;

    switch(empty_stream(std::cin))
    {
    case -1:
        std::cout << "Empty buffer" << std::endl;
        break;
    case 0:
        std::cout << "Error flags in stream" << std::endl;
        break;
    case 1:
        std::cout << "Buffer flushed" << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    std::cin.get(); //This shouldn't be bypassed

    return 0;
}
```